# Image in UItableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimage

Hey
I have a basic table view with an image and text in it. When a cell is tapped I would like something specific to happen whether the image is touched or the rest of the cell. Is there a way to find out what part of the cell has been touched
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add a UITapGestureRecognizer to your imageView, or change the imageView into a custom UIButton that has an image as background.
You would connect them both to your own method, lets call it `imageTapped:`. And you would get the selected indexpath like this:

```
- (IBAction)imageTapped:(id)sender {
    UIView *cellContentView = [sender superview];
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[cellContentView superview];
    NSIndexPath *tappedIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    // do something
}
```

depending on the cell layout the way to get the indexpath has to be adapted.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try somthing like this

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer* tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(someMethodName)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    UIImageView* myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [myImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

When ever user tap once this method will be called so you can keep track of which image is tapped by setting tha tag of imageView = indexPath.row Or any thing of your choice.

Comment: "initWithFrame:CGRectZero " its just for example you can take whatever you want. just  add a TapGesture to it

Comment: That means that I need a custom cell to have a UIImageView though. I was gonna use the default image of a UITableView cell